# Error in sample code SnapStack Plus Android

Tags: android, geolocation, stackmob

I am running a downloaded application called Snaptack Plus from StackMob. The app runs but when I select a button I am getting an error, the stack trace with the error is below. This is where I think the problem is coming from:

> 01-11 17:46:52.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-11 17:46:52.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18584): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-11 17:46:52.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18584):  at com.stackmob.apps.snapstack.extend.BaseActivity.getStackMobGeoPoint(BaseActivity.java:136)

When I step through the code it falls through at this code snippet

```
protected StackMobGeoPoint getStackMobGeoPoint() {
    Location loc = getGPSTracker().getLocation();
    if (loc != null) {
        return new StackMobGeoPoint(loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think the `loc` object is the problem (because this is where it falls through), so can someone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running this from an emulator? it seems that `getGPSTracker()` is returning `null`

Comment: Hi Leaudro, no I am running from the actual phone, and StackMob isn't returning my message, I agree it is in the GPSTracker class because when I comment any calls to this class the error messages are not there. I will trace through the class again. Thanks

Comment: If I add the the project here could someone run it and tell me if they are getting the same thing, because I have been stuck on this this for a while, and I know it is something simple(I think) the people over at stackmob is not getting back with me or anyone for that matter.

Comment: put it on github, and I'll look at it for you!